# Messaging app/Whatsapp send button image

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uibutton

This has to be an incredibly simple question but no amount of googling has rendered an answer. So, to ask the stackoverflow community :)

All I want to know is whether the 'Send' button found in the Messages and Whatsapp apps is a built in button or whether Whatsapp cribbed the design and applied a custom image to their button. If it is built in, I can't find it and so would like to know how to initialise a button with that style.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the sort of curved lightened half-circle at the top of the button? If so, then it is most likely custom made. There are ways to apply those effects to images in CoreGraphics, but it is much easier to just make the image yourself.

Alternatively, there is an app for the Mac which will make these buttons for you, so long as you supply an image. It can be found [here](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/icons/id413612688?mt=12). Hope that helps!